# React typed children syntax

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to understand how to build a react component with very specific type of children, and the syntax I wanted to use was:

```
<Stepper>
    <Stepper.Step>
        Some text/react element child
    </Stepper.Step>
    <Stepper.Step>
        Some other text/element
    </Stepper.Step>
</Stepper>
```

So I wrote out this code as a starting point, but it throws an error even in the case where I don't output anything from this.props: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`.

```
class Step extends Component {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <li>{this.props.children}</li>
        );
    }
}
class Stepper extends Component {
    static Step: typeof Step;
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {

        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ul className="stepper">
                {this.props.children}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

Note that I'm aware that this functionality is provided in some libraries, but I'm not looking to add any new libraries to the core codebase I'm working on.

Comment: I have a feeling that you over-think this problem. `Stepper.step` only means step is the first property of the parent, ex. `export const Stepper = { Step: () => {} }`. You only need to build `Step` component. Somehow you need to sort out which one is instance and which one is your class in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you currently have is a declaration of what type `Step` is. You aren't actually defining the value

```
static Step: typeof Step;
```

It should be this. I'm pretty sure the type will be inferred by TypeScript

```
static Step = Step
```

Comment: Yep, that's it. I thought it had to be a type definition! Thanks man.

Comment: @CBauer There's nothing wrong with just making it a type definition. You can define `Step` outside of the class body if you declare the type inside. So you can have identical behavior by doing `Stepper.Step = Step` outside of the class

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the typeof from when you're defining your compound component from inside Stepper and actually do something like this:

```
  static Step = Step;
```

It should work. Your issue is that typeof will return the type of the component (obj), not the actual component. I replicated your code here and tried it out with that change and it worked:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-thompson-mj1re